# Derive the formula for a capacitive voltage divider?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, voltage, electronics

I've seen the derivation for a resistive voltage divider, Vout = Vin * R2/ (R1 + R2).  For a capacitive divider, Vout is reported as Vout = Vin * C1/ (C1 + C2) - for example see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider.

Can someone walk me through the derivation of this formula?  Can't figure it out, and its killing me!!

Comment: Look at Wikipedia - Voltage Divider - [General Case](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider#General_case) and note that in this case $Z=\frac{1}{\omega C}$.

Comment: The voltages of both capacitors add. The charges in both capacitors are equal.
This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: And, of course, apply Kirchoff's laws.

Comment: @Farcher Ah, it was staring me in the face the whole time and I missed it.  1/C2 / (1/C1 + 1/C2) = 1/C2 / [(C2 + C1) / (C1 * C2)] = 1/C2 * [(C1 * C2) / C1 + C2] = C1 / (C1 + C2)

Comment: Thanks everyone for taking the time to answer!